# Atomic variable with padding (compiler bug?)

Tags: c++, c++14, padding, atomic

I found this weird behavior on Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2) with `-std=c++14`. The following code demonstrates it:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

struct stru {
  std::uint32_t a;
  std::uint64_t b;
};

int main() {
  stru sa{}, sb{1, 1};
  std::atomic<stru> atom(sa);
  std::cout << atom.compare_exchange_strong(sa, sb) << std::endl;
}
```

The output is `0` while I expect it to be `1`. The issue is gone when I change `stru` to:

```cpp
struct stru {
  std::uint64_t a; // original: std::uint32_t a;
  std::uint64_t b;
};
```

The only difference I can see is that the original version has padding, while the modified version does not. Looks like the padding has garbage value in it, which is involved in the `compare_exchange_strong` computation, and cause the unexpected result. I'm wondering what does the standard say about this. Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Why is this tagged [language-lawyer]? What "intricacy" of the standard would this be about? Please don't abuse that tag as a "my question is extra difficult" marker; this is just a normal [c++] question about not even edge-case behavior.

Comment: For complex swaps, you can use an RCU approach, where you swap pointers instead of the object values.

Answer (score 7):

`compare_exchange_strong`() and `compare_exchange_weak`() execute the comparison "[as if by `std::memcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange)", and effects the exchange only if they are "bitwise-equal". Of course, the presence of any padding in the objects involved, that's has not been explicitly initialized, makes the results of the comparison not very useful.

Also note that your structure does not have a formal `==` operator specified; but even if you defined one, it would not be used.

Comment: Just a leaked abstraction in `std::atomic`

Comment: So basically, never use atomic types with padding bits?

Comment: You can certainly use them. Atomic objects have many other features and capabilities, besides these two methods.